# In Azure VM, how can I generate a SAS token for azure blob storage without using the storage account access key?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

The scenario is simple:
My webapp is composed of ReactJS SPA as frontend,  and web api running in VM as backend;
When user need to upload file, the backend generates a URL with SAS token for uploading file into an azure storage account and Blob container.
The backend replies to the frontend SPA with this url, and the user can directly upload file from the local browser to azure blob storage directly, without needing to go cross the backend VM again.

In the backend, I use this code to generate the url with SAS token:

```
function generate_signed_url(BLOB_NAME, AZURE_PRIMARY_KEY) {
    
    const ACCOUNT_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
    const CONTAINER_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME;
    const ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY;

    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName=ACCOUNT_NAME, accountKey=ACCESS_KEY)
      
    //This URL will be valid for 1 hour
    const expDate = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600 * 1000);

    // Generate service level SAS for a blob
    const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
      containerName: CONTAINER_NAME, // Required
      blobName: BLOB_NAME, // Required
      permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"), // Required
      startsOn: new Date(), // Optional
      expiresOn: expDate, // Required. Date type
      cacheControl: "cache-control-override", // Optional
      contentDisposition: "content-disposition-override", // Optional
      contentEncoding: "content-encoding-override", // Optional
      contentLanguage: "content-language-override", // Optional
      contentType: "content-type-override", // Optional
      ipRange: { start: "0.0.0.0", end: "255.255.255.255" }, // Optional
      protocol: SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp, // Optional
      version: "2016-05-31" // Optional
    },
    sharedKeyCredential 
    ).toString();

    SaSURL = `https://${ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/${AZURE_CONTAINER}/${AZURE_BLOB}?${containerSAS}`;
    
    console.log(`SAS URL for blob is: ${SaSURL}`);
    return SaSURL;
}
```

However, this requires me to save the Azure Storage account access key in the VM as an env variable for the project. This is considered bad practice:

```
const ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY
```

Is there any alternatives that is more professional?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I generate a SAS token for azure blob storage without using the storage account access key?

You can generate an SAS token without an account key using **`User delegation key`**.

You need to two packages :

```
import {DefaultAzureCredential} from "@azure/identity";
import {BlobServiceClient,ContainerSASPermissions,
generateBlobSASQueryParameters,
SASProtocol}from "@azure/storage-blob";
```

You can use the below code to achieve this in your backend.

```
function generate_signed_url(BLOB_NAME, AZURE_PRIMARY_KEY) {
    
    const ACCOUNT_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
    const CONTAINER_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME;
   
    const  blobname="spring-flowers.jpg";
    const  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,new  DefaultAzureCredential());
    const  userDelegationKey = await  blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(new  Date(), new  Date(new  Date().valueOf() + 10 * 60 * 1000));
    const  permissions = new  ContainerSASPermissions();
    permissions.list = true;
    permissions.write = true;
    permissions.create = true;
    permissions.delete = true;
    permissions.read = true;
    const  sasOptions = {
        blobname,
        containerName,
        permissions,
        protocol:  SASProtocol.Https,
        startsOn:  new  Date(),
        expiresOn:  new  Date(new  Date().valueOf() + 10 * 60 * 1000)
    };
    const  sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters( 
        sasOptions,
        userDelegationKey,
        accountName
        ).toString();
        const  sasUrl = `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobname}?${sasToken}`;
    const SaSURL = `https://${ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/${AZURE_CONTAINER}/${AZURE_BLOB}?${containerSAS}`;
    
    console.log(`SAS URL for blob is: ${SaSURL}`);
    return SaSURL;
}
```

**Output:**

It returns with SAS-URL like below:

```
SAS URL for blob is = `https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/spring-flowers.jpg?sv=2022-11-02&spr=https&st=2023-07-12T06%3A44%3A08Z&se=2023-07-12T06%3A54%3A08Z&skoid=6e19aa9e-1e69-4a85-85f4-b00099a8da5c&sktid=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47&skt=2023-07-12T06%3A44%3A02Z&ske=2023-07-12T06%3A54%3A02Z&sks=b&skv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sp=rcwdl&sig=xxxx
```

**Browser:**

I checked the URL in the browser it worked successfully.

[image]

> Note: To generate user delegation SAS-token you need
> **`Storage blob data contributor role`**

**Reference:**

[Create a user delegation SAS - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#construct-a-user-delegation-sas)

Comment: I think Storage Blob Data Reader also has permission to generate user delegation key

Answer (score 1):

To generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for Azure Blob Storage without using the storage account access key in an Azure VM, you can use the Azure SDK for Blob Storage in conjunction with Azure Managed Identity.

Answer (score 1):

To generate SAS token without using Storage Account Key, you would need to use something called `System Assigned Managed Identity` which is essentially assigning an identity (kind of like creating a user/service principal) to your VM. There are a number of ways using which you can assign an identity to your VM. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm.

Once you have assigned an identity to the VM, next step would be to assign an appropriate Azure RBAC role to this identity. Please see this link for applicable Azure RBAC data roles for blob storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal.

Once you have done that, then you can use the code mentioned by Venkatesan in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76667871/188096) above.

If you think you would need to do the same thing in different Azure resources (Web Apps, Function Apps etc.), then instead of creating a system assigned managed identity, you would create a `user assigned managed identity`. The process for assigning the permissions and using the identity remains the same. It's just that your overhead of managing multiple identities and permission assignments gets simplified considerably.

To learn more about managed identities, you may find this link helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview.